# I can't find Tag in html

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, web-crawler

```
http://www.wfri.re.kr/client/PublishHp.do?command=view&list_dis_txt=PUB&current_page=1&isu_year=all&list_unq_no=RP00000001847&search_category=&search_keyword=&pub_dt=20170203&topMenuNo=H20000&leftMenuNo=H20100
```

I'm crawling this site.

I am using Python3 and Beautifulsoup

My crawler can not find any tags here.

I want to download the pdf file here.

Beautifulsoup can not scrape any tag from this site.

Why?

```
def second_crawler(second_url):
    second_url = 'http://www.wfri.re.kr/client/PublishHp.do?command=view&list_dis_txt=PUB&current_page=1&isu_year=all&list_unq_no=RP00000001847&search_category=&search_keyword=&pub_dt=20170203&topMenuNo=H20000&leftMenuNo=H20100'
    source_code = requests.get(second_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')
    print(soup)  # for debug
    # tdTag = soup.findAll('td',class_='view_cont')
    # print(len(tdTag))    ## result is 0. Why??
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the code you've used? Easier to help if we know what problems specifically you're running in to...

Comment: @serk OK,  It's very simple. Check my code.

Comment: @ Should I use selenium?

Comment: Even viewing the page directly from within the browser does not return more than a few tags for the header but not much else.

Comment: Right. But, I don't want the header tag. How can I find the body tag?

Comment: what i'm saying is selenium won't work either. Are you sure you've got the right URL?

Comment: @serk Yes, but I could not connect at first Then it works. I don' know why.
exactly, This is the url of a post from this address     http://www.wfri.re.kr/client/PublishHp.do?command=list&isu_year=all&topMenuNo=H20000&leftMenuNo=H20100

I'm very confused.

Comment: I solved it. I use the selenium and time.sleep(5)

Answer (score 0):

The website uses javascript function `javascript:fnc_filedown()` instead of URL to provide the download functionality for PDF files.

For example, when I visit one of the post: `http://www.wfri.re.kr/client/PublishHp.do?command=view&list_dis_txt=PUB&current_page=1&isu_year=all&list_unq_no=RP00000001847&search_category=&search_keyword=&pub_dt=20170203&topMenuNo=H20000&leftMenuNo=H20100`

The download process will only be triggered by using the following line:

```
javascript:fnc_filedown( 'XXX.pdf', '148636884482283162132' );
```

Because that the reference link is stored here:

```
<a href = "javascript:fnc_filedown( 'XXX.pdf', '148636884482283162132' );" class="link01">XXX.pdf</a>
```

Trying to modify your crawler according to the website style is suggested.

Comment: @ Thanks your comments. But I know that.  Even I found the download url. I was wondering how I could see the tags when the html code was executed on the client. but Thanks your comment.